# Elasticsearch doesn't add documents to new index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire (retire now) to index documents that I receive from a socket, I create a new index every day by modifying Model.index_name, the new index is created successfully but documents aren't added to it nor is it added to the old index. I have to do the following workaround to get it working

- Stop rake task (Socket script)
- Delete newly created index
- Start rake task

Then index is created and documents are inserted in a normal manner

Please see my model and my rake indexing script

Model:

```
class LogEntry

 include Tire::Model::Persistence
 index_name {"ip_logstreams_#{Time.now.year}_#{Time.now.month}_#{Time.now.day}"}
 ....
end
```

Rake Script:

```
require 'socket'
require 'net/http'

namespace :offline_logger do
 desc ""

 task :log_listener => :environment do
  begin
   u1 = UDPSocket.new
   u1.bind( '', 3007)
   while (true)
    begin
     now_time = Time.now
     message_array = u1.recvfrom(10000)
     Thread.new do
      message = message_array[0][2..10000]
      message = message.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ")
      msgdatetime = message[0].split(">")[1] +" " + message[1]
      msgpriority = message[2]
      msghostname = message[3]
      i = 4
      msgtext = ''
      while i < message.length
       msgtext = msgtext + message[i] + " "
       i = i + 1
      end
      LogEntry.index_name "ip_logstreams_#{now_time.year}_#{now_time.month}_#{now_time.day}"
      tr = LogEntry.new( :msgdatetime=> Time.parse(msgdatetime), :msgpriority => msgpriority, :msghostname=> msghostname,:msgtext=> msgtext)
      tr.update_index
    end
    rescue => e
     p e.message
    end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Is this the right approach? can the threads be a burden?

Comment: Have you tried debugging what the actual update call looks like? Is it pushing data to an existing index?

Comment: It doesn't index it anywhere, I'm trying to reproduce the issue on my dev machine, what I'm sure of is that code doesn't pass LogEntry.new nor tr.update_index